# How to change proxy settings while using Watin?

Tags: vb.net, proxy, watin

I am using Watin mostly to automate thing I do by hand. Sometimes, I need to change proxy. To do this, I have to set up IE to use a local proxy all the time (listens locally and forwards to a remote porxy), and then by hand change the settings of that program  each time I need to use another proxy.

This is not an elegant solution! It may work, but it is not nice.

So, my question is, how do I change programmatically IE settings while using Watin? I code in VB.NET.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this
http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/